# Running tests for different environment and different versions C#-MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, testing, .net-core, mstest

I am creating an automated test framework to test an API using .NetCore, RestSharp and MsTest. I am looking for ideas to run my tests for 4 different environments (2 different countries, test and live environment each). I will access test data through appsettings.json file (e.g appsettings.eutest.json, appsetings.detest.json, etc).

I could use something like `[DynamicData()]` to pass each test an argument with the key to access each individual .json file, but there is a subset of tests, compatibility tests, where I need to run also again different versions of the API, this is needed to ensure backward compatibility.

```
    [DynamicData("NameOfPropertyWithEnvironments", typeof(BaseClass))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void RegularTest(string envToTest)
    {
        //-- Logic to access data on the .json file
    }

    [DynamicData("NameOfPropertyWithVersions", typeof(BaseClass))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void CompatibilityTest(int versionBackToTest)
    {

    }
```

So far, I have been using also `[DynamicData()]` to pass the versions to be tested as an argument of those particular tests, but I am lost as to how to combine different environments and different versions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q1: when will these tests be run? Assuming 2 scenarios. First is that you want to run these as part of your deployment pipeline. Another is that you want to be able to run these tests locally. Right? Q2: Are you planning to insert test data on your production environment?

Comment: Q1: These tests are integrated with the CI pipeline and will be run after daily deployment. Q2: No, I am not planning to insert any data on my production environment. I have a solution right now and it is to use a custom made  ´[CustomDymanicData]´ attribute that will run each test decorated with it one time for environment and in the case of compatibility tests, setting the attribute's property ´IsCompaitibility = true´ will also run the test for a number of past versions. Thanks a lot for reading and, if you can think of a better solution all suggestions are welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

To run these tests locally, you can create a local.settings.json file in your test project with APIEndpoint and APIVersion settings.
Next, implement a configuration manager that can firstly determine whether you are running the tests locally. If so, read the settings from local.settings.json. If not, read from environment variables. Here is an example of what I use:

```
namespace SomeIntegrationTests.configuration
{
    class Configuration
    {
         public string API_ENDPOINT { get; set; }
         public string API_VERSION { get; set; }
    }

    class ConfigurationManager
    {
    private const string LocalSettingsFile = "local.settings.json";

    private static Configuration _configuration;

    public static Configuration Get()
    {
        if (_configuration == null)
        {
            if (IsLocalRun())
            {
                var localSettings = ReadFile(LocalSettingsFile);
                _configuration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(localSettings);
            }
            else
            {
                _configuration = GetFromEnvironmentVariables();
                Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved configuration from environment variables.");
            }
        }

        return _configuration;
    }

    private static Configuration GetFromEnvironmentVariables()
    {
        var environment = GetEnvironmentVariable("CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT");
        Console.WriteLine($"Current environment is {environment}");

        return new Configuration
        {
            API_ENDPOINT = GetEnvironmentVariable($"API_ENDPOINT.{environment}"),
            API_VERSION = GetEnvironmentVariable($"API_VERSION.{environment}")
        };
    }

    private static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string key)
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key);
    }

    private static bool IsLocalRun()
    {
        var environment = GetEnvironmentVariable("CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT");
        return environment == "local";
    }


    private string ReadFile(string file)
        {
            var projectFolderLocation = // depends on the type of implementation get location of where the local.settings.json is located;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(projectFolderLocation, "configuration", file);
        return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
}
```

}

On your local pc, add an environment variable for "CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT" with value "local" and add local.appsettings.json in your project. In your pipeline add a step to set environment variable values accordingly. When you run the tests during pipeline, settings will be used from the environment variables settings.

Then from your test, you can load the Configuration via ConfigurationManager implementation and then call API_ENDPOINT and API_VERSION.

```
class SomethingTests
    {
        private readonly string APIEndpoint;
        private readonly string APIVersion;
        public SomethingTests()
        {
            var configuration = ConfigurationManager.Get();
            APIEndpoint = configuration.API_ENDPOINT;
            APIVersion = configuration.API_VERSION;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SomethingTests()
        {
            // use APIEndpoint & APIVersion
        }
    }
```

As for running tests against production environments, this doesn't seem like a good idea. You don't want to insert test data on production. Implement automated deployment steps to ensure you tested your API code on test environments and deploy to production after that.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks a lot this is really helpful. I currently read my test data from an appsettings.*env*.json, and have a DataProvider.cs class with a `SetTestEnvironment(string envToTest)` method that will initialize an `IConfigurationRoot Configuration` property and read from the specified file. In order for each test to specify the environment, I created a custom `[CustomDynamicData]` attribute that will run each test one time per environment and will provide a string to be passed as an argument to the test method. Again thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, let me know what you think.